# How to implement a mutli-foreign key in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a project where am required to implement a database relationship between tables(Trip, Truck, Fuel) . Below is the idea :

- A truck has many trips
- Each trip has many trucks
- Each truck has got a fuel associated with a trip.

Now I was hoping to use Eloquent relationships to solve this but am stuck . How do I get a Fuel transaction and map it to a truck and trip ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Short answer is eloquent relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

you can use **pivot table**.

"pivot table is used to build a relationship between two tables where there is a Many to Many relationship."

in your case you can use Many to Many relationship between truck and trip then use fuel like a column in pivot table. it's easier

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent does not support ternary relationships out of the box. This is because typically ternary relationships are incorrectly used when normal binary relationships would be more appropriate. For example I could argue that the `Fuel` entity is actually metadata on the `Truck-Trip` relationship and should be placed on the pivot table instead.

If you are completely 100% certain that your ternary relationship is correctly required then  I think your best bet is to make a separate model `TruckTrip` i.e.:

```
class TruckTrip extends Model {
    public function truck() {
         return $this->belongsTo(Truck::class);
    }
    public function trip() {
         return $this->belongsTo(Trip::class);
    }
    public function fuel() {
         return $this->belongsTo(Fuel::class);
    }
}
```

Then instead of relating Truck, Trip and Fuel directly you could use: `hasManyThrough` e.g.

```
class Trip extends Model {
    public function trucks() {
         return $this->hasManyThrough(Truck::class, TruckTrip::class);
    }
    public function fuel() {
         return $this->hasManyThrough(Fuel::class, TruckTrip::class);
    }
}
```

Similarly you can relate trucks to trips and fuel requirements and fuel requirements to trucks and trips

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is offering many to many relationship but i prefer if you divided by tow relation.
make a table for this relation have the ID of truck  and the ID of trips, then make a relation one to many between truck and this new table and another relation one to many between trip and this new table.
is will be easy for you